# android - remove underline in html input text (not the android EditText)

Tags: android, textbox

Just that, I need to remove a black underline in the text in the html textboxes. I've tried with `text-underline` and `spellcheck=false` and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may help you can do css

**This should do it:**

```
input.myBox
{
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Tested in IE8 (IE7 compatability mode)